# How can I get the RequireJS optimizer to output log results to a file?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, requirejs

I'm using Java+Rhino/Windows to run the RequireJS optimizer with Google Closure Compiler. When I run it from the command line, I see in the command window (presumably, on standard output):

```
java ^
    -classpath "Rhino.jar" ^
    org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main "r.js" ^
    -o "configurationfile.requirejs.js"
```

However, when I try to pipe this output to a file, the file is empty:

```
java ^
    -classpath "Rhino.jar" ^
    org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main "r.js" ^
    -o "configurationfile.requirejs.js" ^
    > "Closure Compiler Test Results.txt"
```

How do I capture the output of the RequireJS optimizer, (and is this a problem common with running any Java program in Windows from the command line)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the output is not on stdout (stream 1), but in stderr (stream 2), so you should need to change `command >"outputFile.txt"` to `command 2>"file.txt"`